# Nilpotent operators.

Tags: linear-algebra

Claim: Let $V$ be a vector space over $C $ .

(V may not be finite dimensional vector space).

Let $T: V \to V $ be a linear transformation.

if $\lambda = 0 $ is $T$'s only eigenvalue than $T$ is nilpotent.

I'm not sure about this claim. I think it's not true, but couldn't find a counter example.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Please, add in the question that you are not assuming $V$ finite dimensional, otherwise this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: If $\lambda = 0$ if the only eigenvalue of $T$, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $\lambda^{\dim V}$. What does the Cayley-Hamilton theorem tells you?

Comment: I thought about this answer but then I wondered whether this argument holds for infinite dimensional vector spaces? I guess not. But I could not find an easy counter example for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: that $T \ ^ {dimV} = 0 $ ? @levap

Comment: @Liad: Yep, and so $T$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you, and what about what @Levent said, is this claim holds for infinite dimensional vector space ?

Comment: Liad: It doesn't. See @Levent's counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

This is not generally true if $V$ is not finite dimensional :

Consider $\mathbb{C}[x]$, the polynomial ring with complex coefficients and let $\delta : \mathbb{C}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x]$ defined by $\delta(f)=d{f}/dx$. Then the only eigenvalue is $0$ but $\delta$ is not nilpotent clearly.

Comment: Operators like your counterexample are sometimes called [quasinilpotent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_operator)